# Passing a null parameter from the model to an action in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am doing an asp .net mvc apllication and i have some problem :
i have this view that contains a link to an action

```
<form >
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Formulaire d'un client</legend>
        @if (Model.Count != 0){
       foreach (string s in Model)
    {
    <a href="@Url.Action("Passer", "Client",(object)@s)"  style="color:blue" >@s</a>
    <br />
      }
        }
        else{
        <label> Pas de projets actuellement</label>
        }
      </fieldset>
  </form>
```

it called this action :

```
public ActionResult Passer(string s)
       {


               Upload.Models.ProjetModels prj = new ProjetModels();
               Upload.Models.CompteModels.Id_directory = prj.GetProjectsId(s);
               int _id_directory = Upload.Models.CompteModels.Id_directory;
               int _id_akeo = prj.GetAkeoIdFromProjet(_id_directory);
               int _id_client = Upload.Models.CompteModels.Id_connected;
               Upload.Models.AkeoModels ak = new AkeoModels();
               string _nom_akeo = ak.GetNameAkeoByID(_id_akeo);

               Upload.Models.DetailsModels detail = new DetailsModels { Id_akeo = _id_akeo, Id_client = _id_client, Id_directory = _id_directory, Nom_akeo = _nom_akeo };
               return View(detail);

       }
```

My problem is the parameter `s` , it is always `null` when i click into the link.

Why this happens? How can i correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is the parameter s , it is always null when i click into the link.

Because your link will look like `/Client/Passer/123`. You could've seen this by looking at the generated HTML, by using Fiddler to debug the HTTP requests or by looking at the browser's address bar after clicking the link.

[`Url.Action()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460348%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)'s third parameter, `routeValues`, is an object that gets mapped to the parameters of the actionmethod that gets invoked. Since your `ActionResult Passer`'s signature is `string s`, you'll need to pass an object that has a string property named `s`.

So change

```
(object)@s
```

To

```
new { s = s }
```

The latter will cause an anonymous object to be created, containing a single `string s` property containing the value of `s`. You might want to look into your variable naming.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
@Url.Action("Passer", "Client", new {s = s})
```

You were not passing arguments as route value. Visit link for elaboration.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460348(v=vs.108).aspx